# VB 6.0 - ServerXMLHTTP - An error occured in the secure channel support

Tags: windows-7, vb6, serverxmlhttp

```vb
Public Sub GetAPIToken(aUserName As String, aPassword As String, aResponse As String)

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object

    Dim strURL As String, strJSON As String

    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    strURL = "https://example.com/v1/users/login"

    strJSON = "{" _

                & Chr(34) & "username" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & aUserName & Chr(34) & "," _

                & Chr(34) & "password" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & aPassword & Chr(34) _

            & "}"
              
    With WinHttpReq

       .Open "POST", strURL, False

       .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

       .Send strJSON   **>> error on this line**

       aResponse = .responseText

    End With

    Set WinHttpReq = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Error:**
`-2147012739 (80072f7d) : An error occurred in the secure channel support`

above code working fine on Windows 10 pc but this error came on Windows 7 pc

Comment: Is UTC on the Windows 7 machine disabled?  Are you running the .exe as admin?

Comment: I'd try disabling UAC but same error, i'm running this code through VB6 development panel (while debugeing)

Comment: Has this Windows 7 machine [TLS1.2 installed and activated](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392)?

Comment: I found that, Remote machine where this API hosted had TLS1.3 security that's why Windows 7 facing problem. Is there any way to solve this issue? In Firefox this API runs perfectly (i think they had TLS1.3 support)

Comment: [Win 7 doesn't seem to support TLS1.3 natively](https://sockettools.com/kb/windows-and-supported-tls-versions/). So besides you implementing it yourself or using a 3rd party library, you're out of luck there, I'm afraid.

Comment: You can try [WinHttpRequest Replacement Class](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket/blob/master/contrib/cHttpRequest.cls) with XP/Win7 compatible TLS 1.3 support in pure VB6 (works on NT4/2000 too) for a source-compatible drop-in replacement of both stock `ServerXMLHTTP`/`XMLHTTP` and `WinHttpRequest` http request objects. Check out repo's README for usage and installation.